# Как обнулить выбранные файлы в Angular

Tags: angular

При повторном выборе хотелось бы чтоб файлы не добавлялись к существующим, а выбирались
заново.

```
<button (click)="inputMultipleFile.click()"
            mat-icon-button matTooltip="Добавить аудио"
            style="margin-left: 10px">
    <mat-icon [ngStyle]="{'color':'green'}">playlist_add</mat-icon>
    <input #inputMultipleFile (change)="selectMultipleAudioFilesAndSave($event);"
             accept=".wav"
             class="custom-file-input"
             multiple="multiple"
             style="display: none" type="file">
</button>
```

Comment: `(click)="inputMultipleFile.value='';"` вероятно, так

Comment: Да, я пробовал такой способ, но у меня он не сработал

Comment: Попробуйте так `(click)="inputMultipleFile.value='';inputMultipleFile.click()"`. Нужен воспроизводимый пример, чтобы конкретней что подсказать.

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю (click)="inputMultipleFile.value=''; - этот клик ожидается в input. Странно, что  даже на оф сайте angular говорится про multiple и ни слова про обнуление файлов перед повторной загрузкой, как будто это само собой разумеющееся.

Comment: Обнуление это всегда значение = '' или = null.. Я вообще первый раз встречаю чтоб замену делали перед повторным выбором, они же и так заменяются. обнулять перед кликом попробуйте у button